# Why was the Bloc party not represented at the MacLeans 2015 Canadian leader debate?

Tags: parties, canada, debate

This is a question about The first 2015 leaders debate held by Maclean’s magazine on August 6th.

The debate included the party leaders for the Conservatives, NDP, Liberals, and Green ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_leaders%27_debates#2015_debates)).

The debate can be replayed [here](http://www.macleans.ca/national-leaders-debate/).

---

As a Canadian who does not speak french, I am use to watching a bilingual debate that includes subtitles in the language that is not currently spoken. If find this useful to make sure I understand what is said by both sides of the given debate. The debate this time was in English and the primary french party leader was missing altogether, this is not normal compared to the historic Canadian debates ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_leaders%27_debates)).

I noticed that even though the Bloc possess two seats (like the Green Party) that they were not represented at the debate.

My original thought was that the debate is restricted to parties with a particular number of seats, but the Green Party leader, Elizabeth May, was present, and the Green party has the same number of seats as the Bloc Party ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_federal_political_parties_in_Canada)).

**Why was Gilles Duceppe, the Bloc leader, not present in the MacLeans 2015 Canadian leader debate?**

Comment: What significance does the following sentence have toward your question?  `As a Canadian who does not speak french I am use to having a debate that includes subtitles when the french is used.`  If I were to guess, I would guess that the debate was in French, and that the debate had no subtitles, and that this caused you to be unable to understand what was being said at the debate, however that is too many guesses for me to feel good about editing it in.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: There is a lot written about the debates so someone who cared sufficiently could probably attempt an answer. There was complexity over who decided to participate in what debate, with not every leader taking part in every debate, often for a mix of reasons some stated and some speculated about. You could start with [Wikipedia's dense explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Canadian_federal_election#Leaders'_debates). Organisations also commonly publish detailed rules, certainly for US presidential debates, and in the UK it has been the subject of litigation as well as negotiation.